# How to handle layout for multiple loaders that finish in unpredictable order?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to build out the example Contacts App code in this Android Tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html

There is sample code there, and it displays only Address information for a given contact. I was able to extend it to pull all the other fields, but I can't get the other fields to display in the layout in the right order.

I think this is because the fragment uses multiple Loaders for each section and does the layout of each one in onLoaderFinished() -- but the order they finish is unpredictable.

Just like a contact's application, I need to be able to dynamically show sections only if there is data for that section. For example, Phones should be first, but if a contact doesn't have phone numbers, then Email should go first, etc.

What would be the best approach to dealing with this? A few possibilities I thought of (and tried unsuccessfully):

1. Instead of building the layout for each cursor in onLoadFinished,
   populate a new Contact class object with the contact
   details. The problem I ran into with this was that I couldn't figure
   out where to build the layout and be sure the Contact object was
   fully populated. I was getting null pointer exceptions.
2. Create a separate ContactLoader class that the fragment calls that
   handles all the Loaders  and returns a pointer to a Contact object.
   Problem: how can I be sure the Contact object is finished being
   populated before I start the layout?
3. Load all the contact data using a single query that calls all the
   data columns at once. I had a lot of trouble setting up the correct
   SELECTION for the query and parsing the Cursor.

Any thoughts?

Here are some snippets of the code ---

Here is where the Loaders are initiated, this is called by onActivityCreated:

> ```
> public void setContact(Uri contactLookupUri) {
>
>           mContactUri = contactLookupUri;
>
>       // If the Uri contains data, load the contact's image and load contact details.
>       if (contactLookupUri != null) {
>           // Asynchronously loads the contact image
>           mImageLoader.loadImage(mContactUri, mImageView);
>
>           // Shows the contact photo ImageView and hides the empty view
>           mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>           mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>
>           // Shows the edit contact action/menu item
>           if (mEditContactMenuItem != null) {
>               mEditContactMenuItem.setVisible(true);
>           }
>
>           // Starts queries to retrieve contact information from the Contacts Provider.
>           // restartLoader() is used instead of initLoader() as this method may be called
>           // multiple times.
>           getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactDetailQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
>           getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactOrgQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
>           getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactPhoneQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
>           getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactEmailQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
>           getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactAddressQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
>           getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactGroupsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
>           getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactEventsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
>
>       } 
>   }
> ```

And here is onCreateLoader() where the loaders start querying the content providers:

> ```
> public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
>
>       final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(mContactUri, Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
>
>       switch (id) {
>       case ContactDetailQuery.QUERY_ID:
>           // This query loads main contact's name
>           return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), mContactUri,
>                   ContactDetailQuery.PROJECTION,
>                   null, null, null);
>       case ContactOrgQuery.QUERY_ID:
>           // This query loads contact's company and title details.
>           return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri,
>                   ContactOrgQuery.PROJECTION,
>                   ContactOrgQuery.SELECTION,
>                   null, null);
>       case ContactPhoneQuery.QUERY_ID:
>           // This query loads contact address details. 
>           return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri,
>                   ContactPhoneQuery.PROJECTION,
>                   ContactPhoneQuery.SELECTION,
>                   null, null);
>       case ContactEmailQuery.QUERY_ID:
>           // This query loads contact email details.
>           return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri,
>                   ContactEmailQuery.PROJECTION,
>                   ContactEmailQuery.SELECTION,
>                   null, null);
>       case ContactAddressQuery.QUERY_ID:
>           // This query loads contact address details.
>           return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri,
>                   ContactAddressQuery.PROJECTION,
>                   ContactAddressQuery.SELECTION,
>                   null, null);
>       case ContactGroupsQuery.QUERY_ID:
>           // This query loads contact groups the contact belongs to.
>           return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri,
>                   ContactGroupsQuery.PROJECTION,
>                   ContactGroupsQuery.SELECTION,
>                   null, null);
>       case ContactEventsQuery.QUERY_ID:
>           // This query loads contact events (birthday, etc) the contact belongs to.
>           return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri,
>                   ContactEventsQuery.PROJECTION,
>                   ContactEventsQuery.SELECTION,
>                   null, null);
>       }
>       return null;
>   }
> ```

And this is onLoadFinished(), which uses a switch to load a buildLayout function for each of the loaders:

> ```
>  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) { 
>
>  // If this fragment was cleared while the query was running      
>  // eg. from a call like setContact(uri) then don't do 
>  // anything.                 
>
>  if (mContactUri == null) { 
>             Log.i(TAG, "mContactUri is null"); 
>             return;   
>  }
>
>   final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =      
>           new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
>           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>
>   switch (loader.getId()) {       
>
>   case ContactDetailQuery.QUERY_ID: 
>
>   // Moves to the first row in the Cursor     
>   if (data.moveToFirst()) {
>
>           // For the contact details query, fetches the contact display name.
>           // ContactDetailQuery.DISPLAY_NAME maps to the appropriate display      
>           // name field based on OS version.
>
>   final String contactName = data.getString(ContactDetailQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
>
>   if (mIsTwoPaneLayout && mContactName != null) {             
>                  // In the two pane layout, there is a dedicated TextView             
>                  // that holds the contact name.   
>                   mContactName.setText(contactName);      
>           } else { 
>                  // In the single pane layout, sets the activity title 
>                  // to the contact name. On HC+ this will be set as 
>                  // the ActionBar title text.
>
>       getActivity().setTitle(contactName);        
>            } 
>   }               
>   break;
>           case ContactOrgQuery.QUERY_ID:          
>
>           if (data.moveToFirst()) {
>          final String company = data.getString(ContactOrgQuery.COMPANY); 
>                    final String title = data.getString(ContactOrgQuery.TITLE);
>
>        //TODO Add Company|Title subtitle here to the ActionBar.                                        
>           }   
>   }   
>   break;
>
>   case ContactPhoneQuery.QUERY_ID:                
>   // This query loads the contact phone details. Same as addresses above.   
>
>   // Loops through all the rows in the Cursor     
>   if (data.moveToFirst()) {
>
>   // Displays the header for this category        
>           final FrameLayout headerLayout = addHeaderLayout(ContactPhoneQuery.header); 
>           mDetailsLayout.addView(headerLayout, layoutParams);
>   do {    
>           // Builds the phone layout 
>           final LinearLayout layout = buildLayout(    
>                data.getInt(ContactPhoneQuery.TYPE),
>        data.getString(ContactPhoneQuery.LABEL),
>        data.getString(ContactPhoneQuery.NUMBER),
>        ContactPhoneQuery.QUERY_ID);       
>           // Adds the new address layout to the details layout 
>           mDetailsLayout.addView(layout, layoutParams);   
>   } while (data.moveToNext());                
>   } else {
>       // If nothing found, adds an empty layout
>           mDetailsLayout.addView(buildEmptyLayout(), layoutParams);     
>   } 
>   break;  
>
>   // Etc for all the Loaders that were called in setContact()
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I put everything to a single Loader and then ran several queries with different SELECTIONs. Much better now!